# Include binary data

Tags: verbatim, characters

How do I include binary data (e.g. the contents of a binary file) in a LaTeX generated PDF-document? If I just copy and paste them into a `verbatim` environment it results in garbage.

Comment: All I see in the above code is `\`7 V??#? <empty line> ?j`. Please be more specific which characters you need.

Comment: This question, [How do I look up a (math) symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) might be relevant.  It's not necessarily math-specific.

Comment: Also, urgency remarks like "please reply as soon as possible" will not get you answers sooner, and may ironically make people less likely to answer you.  Everyone here's a volunteer and all answers are generously provided for free, but nobody's on your schedule.

Comment: @Martin scharrer whatever the symbol may be.. i want to display as it is... Is there any feature in latex for that?

Comment: previously i used Verbatim buts it fails to display the mentioned line.

Comment: @user4852: So, do you want to display binary content from a file? How people are going to read it?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang hey sorry.. i am new to this site. dont know the things.. thanks.

Comment: @Andrey Vihrov  yes..

Comment: @Andrey Vihrov i dont want to people to read it. i just wanna display it as it is. thats it.

Comment: It might be helpful if you let us know what those characters are, i.e. where they come from. Did you open a binary file in a text editor and copy/paste the characters?

Comment: @user4852: This is a very traditional netiquette custom (not specific to this community), see http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent  And it's good advice in general. `:-)`

Comment: @user4852: If these are indeed binary characters then there are no printable symbols for them, so you can't display them "as they are". Often they are displayed as e.g. `<e8>` (where `e8` is the hexadecimal number of the byte). You would need to this conversion by yourself.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer♦ @Matthew Leingangok. thank u

Comment: I completely reformulated the question to match what I think is intended. Because the intended question (and @Andrey's answer) are quite valuable. (To understand the comments above, please look at the edit history.)

Comment: I reopened the question (with two reopen votes already pending) because it is now reasonable phrased after @Caramdir's edit and has a suitable accepted answer with a good number of up-votes (ATM 7). People who down-voted this answer should now also reconsider to remove their vote from the edited question. Six down-votes seem to be a little much anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normally people use a utility such as [`hexdump`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) to view the content of binary files. It could be used to pre-format data for LaTeX, too:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\scriptsize              % Just so that it fits in line
\verbatiminput{dump.txt} % Generated with "hexdump -C" on Linux

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: output of hexdump included in LaTeX]

---

EDIT: It turns out there's a LaTeX package [`hexdump`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hexdump). But it more or less does the same thing as above, the most notable addition being floating dumps with captions.

Comment: "floating dumps with captions" ... the mental image that that phrase creates will stay with me for a _looong_ time.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm glad I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`attachfile`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/attachfile) package. Abstract:

> This package defines an `\attachfile` command that lets you attach arbitrary files to a pdf document. These files are embedded right in the pdf file, so they get transmitted along with it. The package also gives you control over the corresponding icon's properties and various other associated metadata.